# Get separate row for each column change in cdc

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I Created a simple `Employee` table with 3 fields

```
FirstName , LastName , CurrentPayScale
```

This is what I did so far

```
DECLARE @begin_lsn BINARY(10), @end_lsn BINARY(10) , @A NVARCHAR(100)
SET @begin_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_Employee')
SET @end_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()

SELECT  __$operation AS OperationTypeId,
   CASE __$operation WHEN 1 THEN 'has deleted' WHEN 2 THEN 'has added' ELSE 'has updated' END AS [Action],
   ( SELECT CC.column_name + ',' 
     FROM  cdc.captured_columns CC
     INNER JOIN cdc.change_tables CT ON CC.[object_id] = CT.[object_id]
     WHERE capture_instance = 'dbo_Employee' 
       AND sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set(CC.column_ordinal,    EmployeeCDC.__$update_mask) = 1
    FOR XML PATH('')) AS ChangedColumns,
   (SELECT FIRSTNAME + ','
    FROM [cdc].[dbo_Employee_CT]
    WHERE __$start_lsn = EmployeeCDC.__$start_lsn 
      AND __$operation = 3 FOR XML PATH('')) as 'Old Value',
    EmployeeCDC.FirstName  AS 'New Value'
 FROM [cdc].[dbo_Employee_CT] AS EmployeeCDC 
 WHERE EmployeeCDC.__$operation <> 3
```

This query return this result

[image]

Now in third row you can see 2 columns were changed `FirstName and CurrentPayScale`

I just want to see result by each column, I think it can be done with pivot as far as I searched,  but I also don't know how to use pivot.

Comment: You will need have to unflatten the ChangedCOlumns for an efficient PIVOT on the data.

Comment: Also, the pivot command requires all values for the pivoted field to be specified inline. This may be difficult if you have many possible values for column name.

Comment: You pivot on an aggregate such as COUNT, AVG, MIN, MAX...Do you want to know the number of times a specific column and operation has been seen?